# Is there a way to show outlines in a multipatch feature in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, cartography, arcscene, 3d-analyst

When viewed in ArcMap 2D environment, multipatch faces are outlined. When viewed in ArcScene 2.5 D environment, multipatch faces are not outlined, yet the symbol in symbology properties still shows an outline.
Is there a way to show the multipatch faces outlines when viewed in ArcScene?

ArcScene:
[image]

ArcMap:
[image]